# concatenate values in a while loop gone wrong

Tags: c++, string-concatenation, boost-bind

I have a `boost::variant`, which contains various types and I have a string which needs to look like this: **type=D,S**.  The values in the variant are D and S respectively, the key is 'type'.  It is a `map<std::string, std::vector<variant> >` where I'm now iterating the `vector<variant>` part

Now I first apply a static_visitor to my variant to do the appropriate conversion, which in this case might not be needed but for other type it would need conversion to a string.

Then I call this function called `ConcatValues`, part of a helper class.  This class has a `vector<string> v_accumulator` defined, to hold temp results, as this function might be called several times in the while loop and I want to end up with a comma seperated value's list.

The problem is however that my vector `v_accumulator` is always empty on each function call?  How does that make any sense, seeing as it is a class variable.

```
while(variant_values_iterator != values.end())
{
          variant var = *variant_values_iterator;
        boost::apply_visitor( add_node_value_visitor( boost::bind(&SerializerHelper::ConcatValues, helper, _1, _2), key, result), var);
        variant_values_iterator++;
}



std::string SerializerHelper::ConcatValues(std::string str, std::string key)
{
    v_accumulator.push_back(str); //the previous value is not in this vector???
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v_accumulator.begin();

    ss << key;
    ss << "=";

    for(;it != v_accumulator.end(); it++)
    {
        ss << *it;
        if (*it == v_accumulator.back())
            break;
        ss << ",";
    }

    return ss.str();

}


class SerializerHelper
{
public:
    std::string ConcatValues(std::string str, std::string key);

private:
    std::vector<std::string> v_accumulator;
};
```

maybe there is an easier way to concatenate the values of D,S in the value part of my original key/value pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem *might be* that, although `v_accumulator` is a class member, `boost::bind` copies its arguments by default. This means that `ConcatValues` is called on a *copy* of the `helper`, with its very own `v_accumulator` vector.

If you want a reference, you must use `boost::ref` :

```
boost::apply_visitor(add_node_value_visitor(
    boost::bind(&SerializerHelper::ConcatValues, boost::ref(helper), _1, _2), key, result), var);
```

Comment: +1, Alternatively, you can pass the first argument by pointer in the case of binding a member function. The `bind` template will process it correctly: `boost::bind( &SerializerHelper::ConcatValues, &helper, _1, _2 )`.